# Cannot Group 2 Images in MS Word and Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, image-editing

In MS Word and Outlook 2013, I cannot group a pasted image (from Snipping Tool) and an inserted circle. The group by button is grayed out. In fact, I cannot
even select the two images together with CTRL.

What can I do to group these two images?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pasted image is probably part of the paragraph, while the circle hovers in front of the text.

Right-click the pasted image and under `Wrap Text` select something other than `In Line with Text`. For example, select the `Tight` option. You will now be able to select both graphic objects and group them.